# how to pass a parameter from one report to other in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have two reports created and both of them depend on common input. I want to pass the value selected for one report to the other.Ex. I am showing a report for one user (not as user) and want to see some other report for same user, How can I achive this in jasper reports.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give a more thorough example?

Comment: your question is not clear and can you put an example of your code, please put more details.

as I understand from your question, you can use 2 HashMap and pass the parameters by them, you can edit the data as you want it and you have to read more about jasper reports

Comment: Thanks for reply guys. I am not a jasperReports guy and more of a java developer trying to help one colleague. We are moving with using hyperlinks in jasper for the requirement. 
For interest : We wanted to achieve the hyperlink functionality without using hiperlinks :D